# Is there a way to condense ../.. parts of a path out programmatically?

Tags: shell, directory, filenames, symlink

Say for example I have these types of paths to files in a script:

```
/path/to/some/file/../../file1.txt
```

Is there a command I can call such as `readlink` that will convert this path to its actual physical form:

```
/path/to/file1.txt
```

Comment: Note that it may _not_ be `/path/to/file1.txt` if `/path/to/some/file` or `/path/to/some` is a symlink.

Comment: If `file1.txt` is a symlink, do you want to follow it? What do you want to happen if the file doesn't exist or is a broken symlink?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I meant the above was only real files and no symlinks, but I should've said as much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, asked too quickly. On Linux, the answer is to use `readlink` with the `-m` switch:

```
$ readlink -m /home/saml/web/../web_login_form_examples/basic-php-parsing.zip
/home/saml/web_login_form_examples/basic-php-parsing.zip
```

*readlink man page*

```
-m, --canonicalize-missing
       canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the
       given name recursively, without requirements on components existence
```

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't interested in following `file.txt` when it's a symbolic link, and you're assuming that the file exists:

```
filename=/path/to/file1.txt
canonical_directory=$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "$filename")/" && pwd -P)
echo "$canonical_directory/${filename##*/}"
```

This is fully portable (except to some pre-POSIX antiques).